# d3.locale() in d3.js v4, localization

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3.js for charts and now would like to update it to v4.

It was found that `d3.locale()` doesn't work anymore since the translation all date formats are on different language.

How can I fix that? I'm digging the forum, but for v4 I didn't really find it.

Comment: could you add part of the code? the wiki of this project is very complete, https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki but if you add some code we could see which is your specific problem.

Answer (score 16):

You have to use `d3.timeFormatDefaultLocale(definition)` in d3 V4.

Here is an example for German days and months:

```
 d3.timeFormatDefaultLocale({
        "decimal": ",",
        "thousands": ".",
        "grouping": [3],
        "currency": ["€", ""],
        "dateTime": "%a %b %e %X %Y",
        "date": "%d.%m.%Y",
        "time": "%H:%M:%S",
        "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
        "days": ["Sonntag", "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag"],
        "shortDays": ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"],
        "months": ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"],
        "shortMonths": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"]
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`d3.formatLocale(definition)` or `d3.formatDefaultLocale(definition)`

have a look at this documentation
[https://devdocs.io/d3~4/d3-format#formatDefaultLocale](https://devdocs.io/d3%7E4/d3-format#formatDefaultLocale)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you want `d3-time-format` here

https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md